# Writing to XML - Missing lines

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

Python/Programming beginner.  Working on parsing/extracting data from XML.

**Goal:** Take malformed xml (multiple xml files in one .data file) and write it to individual xml files.  FYI - each xml begins with the same declaration in the file, and there are a total of 4.

**Approach** (1) I use readlines() on the file  (2) Find the index of each xml's declaration (3) loop through xml list slices, writing each line to file.  Code below, apologies if it sucks :)

```
For i, x in enumerate(decl_indxs):
    xml_file = open(file, 'w')
    if i == 4:
        for line in file_lines[x:]:
            xml_file.write(line)
    else:
        for line in file_lines[x:decl_indxs[i+1]]:
            xml_file.write(line)
```

**Problem** The first 3 xmls are created without issue.  The 4th xml only writes the first 238 of 396 lines.

**Troubleshooting** I modified the code to print out the list slice used for the final loop and it was good.  I also looped through just the 4th list slice and it outputs correctly.

**Help** Can anyone explain why this would happen? Would also be great to get advice on improving my approach. The more info the better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your approach of finding indexes is good, most probably you messed up with indexes somewhere. And good news, that it's actually not easy to debug, because there are a lot of meaningless integer values. I would try to advice you some useful approaches here.

As far I understand your issue, you need

1. Use `with` context manager to open your original file with multiple XMLs.
2. Split the content of the original file to several string variables, based on finding known declaration header string `<?xml`.
3. Write individual XML valid strings to individual files also using `with` context manager.
4. If you need further work with these XMLs, you definitely should look to specialized XML parsers (`xml.etree`, `lxml`), and never work with them as with strings.

Code example:

```
   def split_to_several_xmls(original_file_path):
    # assuming that original source is correctly formatted, i.e. each line starts with "<" (omitting spaces)
    # otherwise you need to parse by chars not by lines
    with open(original_file_path) as f:
        data = f.read()
    resulting_lists = []
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        if not line or not line.strip():  # ignore empty lines
            continue
        if line.strip().startswith('<?xml '):
            resulting_lists.append([])  # create new list to write lines to new xml chunk
        if not resulting_lists:  # ignore everything before first xml decalartion
            continue
        resulting_lists[-1].append(line)  # write current line to current xml chunk
    resulting_strings = ['\n'.join(e) for e in resulting_lists]  
    # i.e. backwardly convert lines to strings - each one string is one valid xml chunk in the result
    return resulting_strings


def save_xmls(xml_strings, filename_base):
    for i, xml_string in enumerate(xml_strings):
        filename = '{base}{i}.xml'.format(base=filename_base, i=i)
        with open(filename, mode='w') as f:
            f.write(xml_string)


def main():
    xml_strings = split_to_several_xmls('original.txt')  # file with multiple xmls in one file
    save_xmls(xml_strings, 'result')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay I double checked my indexes were correct, and when I printed out the slice it included all data. But, I'm most interested in the improved strategy anyways. I did look into the XML parsers you mentioned, but couldn't figure out how to create multiple trees from my single file.  I could only get a tree for the first root.  While investigating, I came across advice on stack to simplify things and write it line by line.

Comment: Was the purpose of joining the xml lines into a string (resulting_strings) to improve performance when writing? Would skipping it and using a nested for on resulting_lists in the save_xmls function be less efficient?

Comment: Yes, parsers are all about single XMLs. Your task is for pure work with strings. I.e. after your task is done, and you gonna to deal with the result, you want a parser in 95% cases.

Comment: About indexes - I guess that `decl_indxs[i+1]` couldn't work correctly, since there are no 5 index in a list if 4 is the last one. I'm also guessing how it works ever without exception. I need to see `decl_indxs` value, at least. And I still think, that issue in indexes. Probably, in slice index (it falls to zero in cyclic indexing instead of correct `len(file_lines)`).

Comment: And about joining lines - you may use any approach here you like. Join and write, or leave it as is and writelines. For me it is just more clear to have one XML as one string (or Tree object, of course), whenever possible.

Comment: Indexes - I used the if == 4 to get around there not being a 5th index, but that doesn't seem like the proper way to handle it.  Your solution gives me the desired results, so I marked this one answered.

Comment: I agree that joining before you write makes things more clear.  Thanks for taking the time to explain everything :)